# How to create the impression of a div slowly dropping onto something by changing smaller with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I know how to create an animation, but all I've made just looks like the div is resizing.

Any help?

Comment: You want the div to resize, but it should not look like that?

Comment: @MichalKlouda No, I want the div to appear to be sort of 'dropping down' on top of another element, but instead it's just resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use jqueryUI

See this effect

[JQUERY-UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/#default) .See the `transfer effect`

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes and than use switchClass
Your first class will be before effect and the second will be after the effects.
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass

I suggest try animation via css it will give better control.
http://daneden.me/animate/